# How to store active bootstrap tab value using struts 2 tags in jsp and compare with database value in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, struts2

I am creating very simple application using struts 2. I have DB and I want to display tabs and data content automatically based on tab selected. If i am creating tabsby manually defining. I am able to fetch data successfully to tab content. But if i am fetching data from DB, I am not able to display data in tab content based on active tab using struts 2 tags in jsp. Is there any way to compare active tab value with DB column . So that it can check witH DB, if match found, it will display the data.

The following code i am using now.

```
 <ul id="tabs">
<s:iterator value="uniqueAreas">
<li><a href="#" title="tabss">   
<s:property value="area"/> 
<s:property/>      
</a></li>
</s:iterator>
</ul>
<div id="content"> 
<div id="tabbs"> 
<s:set var="tabvalue" value='%{id}' name="tabvalue"/>   
<s:iterator value="activities">
<s:set var="tower" value='%{area}' name="tower"/>                       
<s:if test="#tower == #tabvalue">   
 <h3><s:property value="projectName"/></h3>
<s:iterator value="projectDescriptionList">
<p class="justify "><s:property/></p>
 </s:iterator>   
 </s:if>
  </s:iterator>
  </div>
```

Below is Javascript code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
$("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
$("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

$('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
    $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
    $('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
});  })();
```

Here I am comparing the tab id with one of the column value . So that i can fetch data from DB based on selected tab. But this code is not able to match active/selected tab data with column data. So , data is not coming under tab.

Could you please suggest me what is best approach to get the selected tab data.

DB data and Output url is attached here:
 [DB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWczX.jpg)
   [Output UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiuuZ.jpg)

Comment: What are you doing at the db level? Where the data is stored an how did you map it to the view?